# How can I open apache-activemq docker container file in browser using http://localhost:8088/

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-container

I have created apache-ActiveMQ docker file successfully, but I can't see the result in browser. Also, it does not show any errors, could you please help me?

Dockerfile content is here

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
USER root
COPY apache-activemq-5.16.3-bin.tar.gz /apps/
WORKDIR /apps/
RUN tar -xzf apache-activemq-5.16.3-bin.tar.gz
RUN mv /apps/apache-activemq-5.16.3 /apps/activmqq
WORKDIR /apps/activmqq
EXPOSE 8161
CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "bin/activemq console"]
```

Comment: How are you running the container?  What's the actual error you get?

Comment: i was running with this commend <docker run -d -p 8081:8161 --name activemq -P ganesh/activemq:5.16.3>

Comment: it's no error  <09377f81785a   ganesh/activemq:5.16.3   "/bin/sh -c 'bin/act…"   4 seconds ago   Up 3 seconds   0.0.0.0:8081->8161/tcp, :::8081->8161/tcp   activemq
>  but http://localhost:8081/ this link not working

Comment: can you run this command ```docker logs 09377f81785a``` show us the output